# TestCafe Can't Find Tests, Sort Of

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

All of a sudden, my TestCafe setup can't find named tests.  For example, if I run

**testcafe chrome tests/myfolder/my-test.ts**, it will not run as the test file cannot be found.

However, if I run **testcafe chrome tests/myfolder/*.ts**, the test is launched as expected.

Has anyone ever run across this before.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling testcafe, wrapping the named test path in single quotes, you name it, I've probably tried it.

Comment: Please create a sample to demonstrate the issue: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue

Comment: I'm not quite sure what sample to demonstrate you are looking for.  What I've stated in the question is the sample.  Naming a singular test in a folder doesn't work as it is indicated tests can't be found in the tests/myfolder location.  If I substitute the test name in the command with *.ts, then the test will run.

Comment: I am asking for such an example because the described issue is not common. I tried to reproduce the problematic behavior, but everything works as expected. Thus, your sample should at least demonstrate the folder structure with your test files

Comment: Here is the directory structure of the folder I'm running the tests from on the command line...

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not manage to reproduce the issue using the same folder structure as you. TestCafe team would be happy to assist you with the issue. However, we need a sample repository that we can run on our machines to reproduce the described behavior.